# Type Mismatch when Calling Month on a valid date

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am having an issue with Ms Access 2010 processing Dates using the Month and Year functions. Oddly enough the day function works...

```
?Day(#12/25/2014#)
 25 
?Month(#12/25/2014#)
 error
?Year(#12/25/2014#)
 error
```

The error I am getting is a Run-time Error '13' / Type Mismatch.  An help diagnosing he root cause or a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Could it be because it thinks you are setting a date as the 12 day of the 25th Month?  Try using #20141225# or if that doesn't work #25/12/2014#

Comment: Make sure that you do not have any broken or missing references.

Comment: @TobyAllen That would be #2014/12/25# or #2014-12-25#

Comment: you didn't mention version of msaccess, but 2003 works well: ?Day(#12/25/2014#)
 25 
?Month(#12/25/2014#)
 12 
?Year(#12/25/2014#)
 2014

Comment: @4dmonster It will work well right up to 2013, the problem suggests a damaged or missing reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect Month and Year have been redefined in your code.

Try typing just the 7 characters `?month(` into the debug window without pressing Enter, and see what the IntelliSense tip pops up with.

If it says `Month(Date)` then all is working fine.

If it says something like `Local Month As Variant` then that is what you need to fix.

This code reproduces your problem, complete with the same error message:

```
    Public Sub MonthFail()
    Dim Month, x
    x = Month(#12/25/2014#)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Tom, you were exactly right.  In another module there was a variable named Month and after I changed Month to vMonth there were no issues.  Thanks!